# Making 3D graphics showing sphere eversions

Tags: plotting, graphics, topology

[image: figure]
[image: figure]

Were these pictures made by *Mathematica* or MATLAB? And how could I make ones like them?

Comment: Why not link to the reference/paper you saw these in?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry I only have these two screenshots not the whole paper...

Comment: One can easily search the web for the words at the top of the first image to find this: [Chéritat, "Yet another sphere eversion", arXiv:1410.4417](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.4417)

Comment: @Rahul Okey. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your question is borderline off-topic, I suggest that in the future you show more effort on your side, for example by running a web search yourself as shown by Rahul. Also show diligence by including information such as the equations involved, when available. Furthermore, try to narrow down your question to something more specific.  Your questions are and will be most welcomed, but it will help if you ask something that can be answered. *"how could I make them?"* is too broad. Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've read the paper Rahul linked to. The first picture ought to be easily doable with B-splines; styling of course would be left up to a raytracer, as Henrik notes.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

These pictures must have been made with a raytracer. By default, *MATLAB* and *Mathematica* use shading only for rendering 3D-images.

But one can use both *MATLAB* and *Mathematica* to generate the geometry as a triangle mesh. Afterwards one can render the images by using an external, dedicated raytracing tool, e.g. *blender*, which has a nice user interface. I also made good experience with running *POVray* from the command line.

Anyways, these pictures are highly artistic and it must have taken several days to design them.